# Can't get DIV to center inside of image slideshow

Tags: html, css, slideshow

First time here asking a question, been using this for a long time. I'm relatively new to coding and I'm doing a project for school.

I have an image slideshow on my website, based on the one created by W3schools and inside that slideshow I have created a caption box with a semi-transparent box background. For some reason I cannot seem to get that caption box centered horizontally. The code for my slideshow currently looks like this:

```
<!--- Image slideshow --->
<div class="slideshow-container">
<a href="#slideshow" id="slideshow">
    <div class="text">
        <div class="mySlides fade">
            <div class="numbertext">1 / 5</div>
            <img src="images/city2.jpg" style="width:100%">
            <div class="text2">Caption 1</div>
        </div>
        <div class="mySlides fade">
            <div class="numbertext">2 / 5</div>
            <img src="images/elevator3.jpg" style="width:100%">
            <div class="text2">Caption 2</div>
        </div>
        <div class="mySlides fade">
            <div class="numbertext">3 / 5</div>
            <img src="images/nanotech2.jpg" style="width:100%">
            <div class="text2">Caption 3</div>
        </div>
        <div class="mySlides fade">
            <div class="numbertext">4 / 5</div>
            <img src="images/hyperloop3.jpg" style="width:100%">
            <div class="text2">Caption 4</div>
        </div>
        <div class="mySlides fade">
            <div class="numbertext">5 / 5</div>
            <img src="images/vfarming2.jpg" style="width:100%">
            <div class="text2">Caption 5</div>
        </div>

        <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
        <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
    </div>
</a>
</div>
```

This CCS and rest of the website can be seen at the link below. I've replaced the images with placeholders of the same size. http://codepen.io/Ethan_Matlack/pen/MyNdWG

Based on other post I've seen on stack overflow I've tried assigning the parent element (text) a

```
 display: inline-block
```

attribute and the child element (text2) a

```
 text-align: center
```

attribute but this didn't work. For whatever reason no matter what I do it won't center. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Here is all of the relevant CSS code:

```css
/* ----------------------------------------------------------------- */
/* Slideshow CSS3 */
* {box-sizing:border-box}
body {font-family: Verdana,sans-serif;margin:0}

.mySlides {
 display:none;
 width: 100%;
 max-width: 1300px;
 height: 600px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
.w3-left, .w3-right, .w3-badge {
 cursor:pointer
}
.w3-badge {
 height:13px;
 width:13px;
 padding:0
}

/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
 max-width: 1300px;
 max-height: 600px;
 position: relative;
 margin: auto;
}

.slideshow-container2 {
 max-width: 650px;
 height: 300px;
 position: relative;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev, .next {
 cursor: pointer;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 top: 50%;
 width: auto;
 padding: 16px;
 margin-top: -22px;
 color: white;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 18px;
 transition: 0.6s ease;
 border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
 right: 0;
 border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover, .next:hover {
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}

/* Caption text */
.text {
 display: inline-block;
}

.text2 {
 text-align: center;
 border-radius: 3px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
 color: #f2f2f2;
 font-size: 15px;
 padding: 8px 12px;
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 16px;
 width: 60%;
}

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
 color: #f2f2f2;
 font-size: 12px;
 padding: 8px 12px;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
}

/* Fading animation */
.fade {
 -webkit-animation-name: fade;
 -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
 animation-name: fade;
 animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
 from {opacity: .4} 
 to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
 from {opacity: .4} 
 to {opacity: 1}
}

/* On smaller screens, decrease text size */
@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
 .slprev, .slnext,.text {font-size: 11px}
}
/* ----------------------------------------------------------------- */
```

EDIT: I've opted to put only the CSS into the snippet as this is relevant to the questions and will help anyone else easily find an answer. In order for the snippet to be functional I would need almost all the rest of my code which isn't relevant to the question. The full code can be seen in use at the codepen link.

Comment: Please use the snippet functionality to include the relevant CSS code.

Comment: The text inside the `text2` div _is_ centered in my browser. Are you seeing something different? Or did you want the div itself (displayed as a black bar) to be centered?

Comment: Ah sorry should have specified. I'm trying to get the black bar centered. I already have the text centered.

Comment: Actually, you should have put the HTML and the CSS _together_ in the same snippet.

Comment: Thanks for the info Xufox. I will update this and remember to do that next time. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add `left: 0` and `right: 0` to your `.text2` class and then use `margin: 0 auto;` to center it on the middle of its container.

[Updated codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EKqzvz).

Comment: Thanks! This solved it. Before I was just using `margin: 0 auto` and not the left and right attributes. I'm going to mark this as the answer but it seem there is a delay before I can. (I'm new here.)

Comment: @EthanMatlack I am glad that it helps to you :) And yes, there is some minutes until you can accept an answer.

Comment: This works too and I like this method better than mine. I'm surprised there's so many different ways to do this.

Comment: Yeah this was really simple and here I was with all sorts of complex attempts at trying to fix it. Lol

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is make the following modifications to your text2 class:

Add

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

and change

```
position: relative;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways of doing this. The one I'd use is the following. Just add this to your css:

```
.mySlides {
    position: relative;
}
.text2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%);
    /* removed bottom: 16px; */
}
```

This will always center matter the height or width of your `.text2` element

http://codepen.io/mattmuirhead/pen/wGVbrr

edit: This is to center both horizontally and vertically

Comment: But the OP only wants to center it horizontally.

Comment: Technically they didn't define that, they said they wanted it centered, to me this is centered.

Comment: Yes, that's also true but I think it does not have a lot of sense to put it vertically centered in this case. Also, he was trying to do it with `inline-block` and `text-align: center` so I think it could be guessed that he only wanted it horizontally centered. Anyway, as the OP do not say it specifically, it could be :)

Comment: Sorry I didn't clarify. I meant centered horizontally. Will update post with clarification. I got my solution above though. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your `text2` class's CSS:

```
left: 50%;
margin-left: -30%;
```

The class is already absolutely positioned. So the `left: 50%` attribute moves the left side of the element to the center. Then the `margin-left: -30%` moves it back to the left by half of its width (the element's width is `60%` according to the CSS you provided).

Comment: My goal is to make the page so it scales properly on all devices and browsers widths so I'm trying to avoid setting definitive sizes or in this case something that is relative to a definitive size. (Because the image size that this references scales with browser meaning this number would change.)

Comment: @EthanMatlack The code I provided will always work as long as the `text2` class is set to `width: 60%`. Regardless though, you're probably better off with Error404's answer. It's less hacky and will work even if the element's width setting changes.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you're doing it the wrong way around.
The parent gets the text-align property, and the child the display.

so:

```
.text {
  text-align:center;
}
.text2 {
  display:inline-block; 
  position:relative;
}
```

you can't do this with an absolute positioned element.
If it HAS to be position:absolute; you could also use the transform property as follows:

```
.text2 {
  position:absolute;
  left:50%
  -webkit-transform:translateX(-50%);
  transform:translateX(-50%);
}
```

Why does that work? Because Translate moves the element based on it's OWN width, whereas position:absolute; left:50%; moves the element based on it's PARENT width.